# Intersection indices by rows

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, intersection, vectorization

Given these two matrices:

```
m1 = [ 1 1;
       2 2;
       3 3;
       4 4;
       5 5 ];

m2 = [ 4 2;
       1 1;
       4 4;
       7 5 ];
```

I'm looking for a function, such as:

```
indices = GetIntersectionIndecies (m1,m2);
```

That the output of which  will be

```
indices = 
          1
          0
          0
          1
          0
```

How can I find the intersection indices of rows between these two matrices **without using a loop** ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
function [Index] = GetIntersectionIndicies(m1, m2)
[~, I1] = intersect(m1, m2, 'rows');
Index = zeros(size(m1, 1), 1);
Index(I1) = 1;
```

By the way, I love the inventive solution of @Shai, and it is much faster than my solution if your matrices are small. But if your matrices are large, then my solution will dominate. This is because if we set `T = size(m1, 1)`, then the `tmp` variable in the answer of @Shai will be T*T, ie a very large matrix if `T` is large. Here's some code for a quick speed test:

```
%# Set parameters
T = 1000;
M = 10;

%# Build test matrices
m1 = randi(5, T, 2);
m2 = randi(5, T, 2);

%# My solution
tic
for m = 1:M
[~, I1] = intersect(m1, m2, 'rows');
Index = zeros(size(m1, 1), 1);
Index(I1) = 1;
end
toc

%# @Shai solution
tic
for m = 1:M
tmp = bsxfun( @eq, permute( m1, [ 1 3 2 ] ), permute( m2, [ 3 1 2 ] ) );
tmp = all( tmp, 3 ); % tmp(i,j) is true iff m1(i,:) == m2(j,:)
imdices = any( tmp, 2 );
end
toc
```

Set `T = 10` and `M = 1000`, and we get:

```
Elapsed time is 0.404726 seconds. %# My solution
Elapsed time is 0.017669 seconds. %# @Shai solution
```

But set `T = 1000` and `M = 100` and we get:

```
Elapsed time is 0.068831 seconds. %# My solution
Elapsed time is 0.508370 seconds. %# @Shai solution
```

Comment: blah. just typed this too... +1

Comment: @SamehKamal I just updated my answer to include a speed test, demonstrating the circumstances under which my solution will prove optimal relative to the solution of Shai.

Comment: no you were right, when I wrote the code I used `[~,I1,~]=intersect(m1,m2,...)` , but at your original code you used `intersect(m2,m1,...)` so the proper location of the output is `[~,~,I1]`... my bad for not noticing that. Besides that, I wish these answers will always come so quickly and well articulated in SO...

Comment: @natan Actually, it was only after I saw your comment that I realized I should switch around `m1` and `m2` in my code, and then I could eliminate consideration of the third output entirely, so thanks for that :-)

Answer (score 3):

How about using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)

```
function indices = GetIntersectionIndecies( m1, m2 )
    tmp = bsxfun( @eq, permute( m1, [ 1 3 2 ] ), permute( m2, [ 3 1 2 ] ) );
    tmp = all( tmp, 3 ); % tmp(i,j) is true iff m1(i,:) == m2(j,:)
    indices = any( tmp, 2 );
end
```

Cheers!

Comment: Please, Can you put your code in the form of `function indecis = GetIntersectionIndecies(m1,m2)`

Comment: What a fascinating solution! +1

Comment: I just did a quick speed test, and your solution works great if `size(m1, 1)` is small, but suffers as the size of the matrices increases, since `tmp` gets very large. But still, a very creative solution!